# Creation a native code in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, native, react-native, native-code

I have some problems in creation of native code in new version of Android Studio 3.3. In the previous versions it was easy: create a project and check the “Include C++ support”
But in the new version that option disappeared and everything changed. I’m trying to find how to include c++ support but I can’t. Can you help me, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `Native C++` option (bottom right)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code
i think they removed auto use for c++ in this version and you need to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This [has changed](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/) in the January 2019 release (version 3.3), as new projects use CMake by default:

> For new projects, Android Studio uses CMake by default, but also supports ndk-build for existing projects. To learn how to include native code in your Android application, read [Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html). To learn how to debug native code with lldb, see [Debug Native Code](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#debug-native).

Following the link in the quote will give you an up-to-date walkthrough on how to add C++ code to your project.